# @Scheduled job blocking Quartz job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have managed to configure two jobs in my Spring Boot app as below.

1. Echo job scheduled for every 3 minutes.

```
@Service
public class TransactServiceImpl {

@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${interval}")
  @Override
  public void echo() { /* implementation ommitted*/
  }
}
```

In the logs, I see `"logger":"com.pip.service.impl.TransactServiceImpl", "msg":"Echo", "thread":"scheduling-1"` and this keeps coming every 3 mintues.

2. I have also configured a Quartz job scheduled every minute which works fine only when I comment out the `//@Scheduled` of the `echo` job. When I run it both together, only the echo job gets triggered. I believe this is because of the thread that's supposed to execute Quartz job is getting blocked somehow or something to do with ThreadPool, I suppose.  The quartz job is supposed to run only once at night, but I kept it as 1 minute for testing purposes. I need to get these jobs working together asynchronously. Here are my quartz configurations.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
    beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
  }

  @Override
  protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
    final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
    beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
    return job;
  }
}
```

ShedulerConfig

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired
  private QuartzProperties quartzProperties;

  @Bean
  public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {

    SchedulerJobFactory jobFactory = new SchedulerJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(quartzProperties.getProperties());

    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(properties);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setTriggers(repoTriggerConfig().getObject());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public JobDetailFactoryBean repoJobConfig() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(RepoJob.class);
    jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
    jobDetailFactory.setGroup("pip-scheduler-group");
    return jobDetailFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public CronTriggerFactoryBean repoTriggerConfig() {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(repoJobConfig().getObject());
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/1 0 ? * * *");
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setGroup("pip-scheduler-group");
    return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
  }
}
```

RepoJob

```
@Slf4j
public class RepoJob implements Job {

  @Autowired RepoService repoService;

  @Autowired RepoUtil repoUtil;

  @Override public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext)
      throws JobExecutionException {

    boolean success = repoService.createFile();

    if (success) {
      try {
        boolean isSuccess = repoUtil.sendInfo();
        if (isSuccess) {
          log.info("Info sent success");
        }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

quartz properties from application.yml

```
  quartz:
    properties:
      org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
      org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
      org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
      org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: pip-clustered-scheduler
      org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
      org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties: true
      org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
      org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: qrtz_
      org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.class: org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
      org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.cleanShutdown: TRUE
  jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    job-store-type: jdbc
```

Uses the same database schema for application & quartz tables. I am not sure if there is anything wrong in the way quartz is configured.

Could anyone please guide me here. This is my first time using Quartz. Thank you.

Start up log:

```
 

 INFO [StartupInfoLogger.java:55] Thread:[main] Starting PipDvsApplication using Java 11.0.11 on B720L with PID 22720 (D:\Projects\pip-dvs-app\target\classes started by U55097 in D:\Projects\pip-dvs-app)
 INFO [SpringApplication.java:663] Thread:[main] The following profiles are active: dev
 INFO [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Thread:[main] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
 INFO [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Thread:[main] Starting service [Tomcat]
 INFO [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Thread:[main] Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
 INFO [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Thread:[main] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
 INFO [HikariDataSource.java:110] Thread:[main] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
 INFO [HikariDataSource.java:123] Thread:[main] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
 INFO [IsoClient.java:77] Thread:[main] Connected with host:216.76.27.250 , post:20500, status:false
 INFO [StdSchedulerFactory.java:1220] Thread:[main] Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
 INFO [SchedulerSignalerImpl.java:61] Thread:[main] Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
 INFO [QuartzScheduler.java:229] Thread:[main] Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
 INFO [ShutdownHookPlugin.java:120] Thread:[main] Registering Quartz shutdown hook.
 INFO [QuartzScheduler.java:294] Thread:[main] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'pip-dvs-clustered-scheduler' with instanceId 'B720L1633520106597'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 20 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.

 INFO [StdSchedulerFactory.java:1374] Thread:[main] Quartz scheduler 'pip-dvs-clustered-scheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
 INFO [StdSchedulerFactory.java:1378] Thread:[main] Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
 INFO [QuartzScheduler.java:2293] Thread:[main] JobFactory set to: com.pip.job.SchedulerJobFactory@b3c7c75
 INFO [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Thread:[main] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
 INFO [QuartzScheduler.java:547] Thread:[main] Scheduler pip-dvs-clustered-scheduler_$_B720L1633520106597 started.
 INFO [StartupInfoLogger.java:61] Thread:[main] Started PipDvsApplication in 58.08 seconds (JVM running for 60.088)
 INFO [DirectJDKLog.java:173] Thread:[RMI TCP Connection(2)-192.168.29.216] Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: You should first check the table `qrtz_job_details` table in order to find wether the quartz job entry is being persisted in database or not. it will help you in identifying wether the job is being configured properly or not. if there is an entry then look for associated trigger table `qrtz_corn_triggers`

Comment: @msucil The tables do get updated with details on application startup. Should I convert the `echo` job to a quartz job in order to make it part of the same quartz thread pool? Maybe I don't fully understand how it works. Also, should I be cleaning up the quartz tables on each startup? The application now starts up with logs that says `Scheduler started` but then no further activity can be seen in the log. Please guide